# Trying to Run Docker mailcow Server and Website on same Apache2 Server

Tags: apache, apache2

rly struggeling getting things to run. Trying to get my Website running next to my docker mailcow server. The mailcow server running fine with reverse proxy but i don"t know how to set my conf file for my website.

This is my conf file for my docker mailcow server running great:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mail.mydomain.io
ServerAlias autodiscover.*
ServerAlias autoconfig.*
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^autoconfig. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}# [L,NE,R=permanent]
RewriteRule ^ /autoconfig.php [PT]
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyAddHeaders On
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "http"
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mail.mydomain.io  [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =autodiscover.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =autoconfig.*
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName mail.mydomain.com
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyAddHeaders On
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.io/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.io/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

And now i"am trying to build a conf file for my website:

What i"ve done so far is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mydomain.io
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.io

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mydomain.io_error.log
        CustomLog ${Apache_LOG_DIR}/mydomain.io_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache2 is crashing when i enable the second one. I did the mailcow docker server a year ago through a tutorial. and now want to extend it with a website and a nextcloud server.

I can provide you with error logs if you need.

Maybe you know how i can configure it with https to.

Ty for help greetz